# How to calculate "saw": daily counter from source counter

Tags: prometheus

How to calculate "saw": daily counter from source counter?

How to calculate bottom line from top line?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible (Prometheus v2.25). When you want to visualize the 'profile' of this increase over the day, you can use the `rate` and the `increase`.

`rate()` returns you a value calulated down to events per second (which might be quite low if you have less then 100 events per day)

`increase()` might be better suited in that case as it returns you the absolute number of counter steps within the range.